# how to concatenate two array element values in php by special charcter?

Tags: php, arrays, concatenation

i have two arrays given below

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2013-07-09
    [1] => 2013-07-16
    [2] => 2013-07-23
    [3] => 2013-07-30
)

Array
(
    [0] => 2013-07-16
    [1] => 2013-07-23
    [2] => 2013-07-30
    [3] => 2013-08-06

)
```

i want to concatenate two array element values by special character.given output below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2013-07-09 : 2013-07-16
    [1] => 2013-07-16 : 2013-07-23
    [2] => 2013-07-23 : 2013-08-30
    [3] => 2013-08-30 : 2013-08-06

)
```

Comment: $join = array_map(function($r, $t) { return $r . ' : ' . $t; }, $rr, $tt));

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try with `array_map` like this

```php
$combined = array_map(function($a, $b) { return $a . ' : ' . $b; }, $array1, $array2);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$a1 = new ArrayIterator($array1);
$a2 = new ArrayIterator($array2);

$it = new MultipleIterator;

$it->attachIterator($a1);

$it->attachIterator($a2);

foreach($it as $e) {

        $array3[] = $e[0]." : ".$e[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

do this , `$combined_array` is your answer

```
$array1 = Array
(
    [0] => 2013-07-09
    [1] => 2013-07-16
    [2] => 2013-07-23
    [3] => 2013-07-30
);
$array2 = Array
(
    [0] => 2013-07-16
    [1] => 2013-07-23
    [2] => 2013-07-30
    [3] => 2013-08-06

);
$combined_array = array();
foreach($array1 as $key=>$value)
{
    $combined_array[$key]=$value." : ".$array2[$key];
}
```